# Robot framework - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 49: ordinal not in range(128) while inputting text

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I'm querying values from database to enter in the input field using selenium. However, for certain values I get the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position
>   49: ordinal not in range(128)

I'm getting the error when the value to enter in the text field is something like **'Décor'**. I understand that the issue with the character **"é"**. How can I overcome this error?

Robot code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    DatabaseLibrary

*** Test cases ***
Test
    ${value}      Get value from database
    Input text    ${locator}    ${value}

*** Keywords ***
Get value from database
    ${queryResults}    Query    ${query}
    [Return]    ${queryResults}
```

**Note:** The error specifically occurs when inputting the text into the field(Step 2). Logging the same value to the console works fine.

Comment: @DebanjanB - I did go through the answers in the question you have mentioned but I couldn't find a resolution for my problem. When I convert the **'D\xe9cor'** to a raw string it is entered into the input text as is. But I want to enter **"Décor"**. Problem is that the value from database is getting saved in the tuple as   **'D\xe9cor'**.

Comment: `\xe9` is `é` (`u'\xe9'`) encoded as cp1252 or latin-1.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - Yep. My question is , how do I get the value as ''é" instead of "\xe9"?

Answer (score 0):

This being py2 my suspect would be the actual type of the variable you use (`value`); it may be a bytestring with the high-ascii characters in encoded form.

Just before using it in `Input Text`, convert it to unicode:

```
${value}=    Decode Bytes To String    ${value}
```

If that fails - or it doesn't produce the desired result, try with `Convert To String`:

```
${value}=    Convert To String    ${value}
```

I suspect the latter though will preserve the "offending" characters in their encoded form, e.g. "D\xe9cor". Do let me know in the comments, I'm quite curious :)

Comment: Decoding with the encoding set as UTF-8 returns error **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 36: invalid continuation byte**. And 'Convert to String' converts it into a raw string. Same behavior as mentioned in the question comments.

Comment: What's the type of `value`? Run this - `${the type}=  Evaluate  type($value)` - note the lack of curly brackets around the variable, and then `Log To Console  ${the type}`.

Comment: <type 'str'>. I'm getting even more curious now!

Comment: For now I'm restricting fetching the data with the particular character (é). I know this is a workaround. This also vastly reduces my test data set since most of the data contains the character. But that's what I could think of now.

Comment: In python2.7 bytearray/bytestring's type is 'str'; a unicode string is of type 'unicode'; so my suspicions are on track, let's try getting it to work for you :)

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. Your inputs are highly helpful. Thanks!

Comment: did you get any fix for this? I've been unable to get it to work!