# ROBOT FRAMEWORK : 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: robotframework, python-unicode

I need some help on how to fixed this error in Robot Framework

This is under my Test Edit

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
test_1
Open Browser    https://robotframework.org/    chrome
```

but when I run it, it gives me this result

```
command: robot --argumentfile 
c:\users\montec~1\appdata\local\temp\RIDEhqx71l.d\argfile.txt --listener 
C:\Python27\lib\site- 
packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:49543:False 
C:\Users\montec\Documents\RobotFramework\TestProject
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 16: ordinal not in 
range(128)
```

**argfile.txt**

```
--outputdirc:\users\montec~1\appdata\local\temp\RIDEhqx71l.d-Coff-W106
```

I am using **python 2.7.16** and **wxPython2.8-win64-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27** **RIDE**

Comment: It looks like the problem might be in the listener. What happens if you remove the listener, does the problem still show up?

Comment: i tested to remove this c:\users\montec~1\appdata\local\temp\RIDEhqx71l.d\argfile.txt but when restarting RIDE and run it again, it has the same error. @BryanOakley

Comment: I didn't ask about removing the argfile, I asked about removing the listener.

Comment: @BryanOakley - This doesn't seem to be an issue with the listener but something to do with utf encoding in python 2.x. I'm also facing this issue while querying data from DB. ( [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800265/robot-framework-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe9-in-po) & [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258693/problem-with-select-from-database-if-using-unicode-character)). I've been unsuccessful in resolving this issue so far!